# One Question about Exponential Variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

This is a problem from Richard Durrett's *Essentials of Stochastic Processes*.

Excited by the recent warm weather Jill and Kelly are doing spring cleaning at their apartment. Jill takes an exponentially distributed amount of time with mean $30$ minutes to clean the kitchen. Kelly takes an exponentially distributed amount of time with mean $40$ minutes to clean the bath room. The ﬁrst one to complete their task will go outside and start raking leaves, a task that takes an exponentially distributed amount of time with a mean of 1h. When the second person is done inside, they will help the other and raking will be
done at rate $2$. (Of course the other person may already be done raking in which case the chores are done.) What is the expected time until the chores are all done?

Am I doing all right if I got $\dfrac{502}{7}$ minutes?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "mean time"? Do you mean "Net work/Mean rate of work"?

Comment: Mean time is the reciprocal of the rate in the exponential distribution. That is to say, the time Jill needs to clean the kitchen follows an exponential distribution with $\lambda=\frac{1}{30}$ and mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}=30$.

Comment: Incidentally this reciprocal of rate happens to be "Net work/Mean rate of work".

Comment: I see. Any thoughts about the original problem?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with expected times on processes that theoretically take infinite time.

Comment: I think this problem is just about probability.

Comment: Yes it is. *Expected time* or *Expectation of a random variable* is probability, but a branch I am unfamiliar with. I will try to arrive at a solution, and post it though.

Comment: I get the same answer. I modelled the problem as a Continous Time Markov Chain with 7 states. Then I worked my way backwards from the terminal state, for each state calculating the expected time until reaching the terminal state.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us how you calculated the result? I am curious

Comment: Sabyasachi: Thank you.

Jacob: Is it safe to say that if the earlier of the two, say A, finishes raking before the other, say B, finishes her first job, then the mean is the time B uses to finish her first job, otherwise it is that time plus an exponential variable with rate 1/30?

Comment: OP: How did you get this result?

Comment: See above. If, say, Jill finishes cleaning the kitchen earlier than Kelly cleaning the bathroom, and Jill is done raking before Kelly is done inside, then the total time is just the time Kelly takes. But if Jill has not finished raking when Kelly is done inside, we need to consider both the time Kelly takes and the value of the exponential variable with rate 1/30. The same holds in the case when Kelly finishes first.